# Trying to get results from 3 different tables using sql or linq query

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework-core, left-join

I'm very new to SQL/LINQ and could really use your help.

I have 3 tables:

**Invitation** table

```
| InviteId | Name     | Email        | SalesAgentId |   |
|----------|----------|--------------|--------------|---|
| 9        | John Doe | john@doe.com | 1            |   |
```

**SalesAgent** table

```
| SalesAgentId | UserId | Active       |
|--------------|--------|--------------|
| 1            | 2      | true         |
```

**User** table

```
| UserId | Name                                 | Email                             |
|--------|--------------------------------------|-----------------------------------|
| 2      | Sales Guy                            | sales@agent.com                   |
```

Trying to generate a list of a given SalesAgent that should contain that SalesAgent's info along with info of the user that has been invited by the sales agent (from the **Invitation** table)

**Goal**:
Trying to Get a list of users (both from the **Invitation** table and **User** table that are tied to the SalesAgent Id (either the user is the sales agent himself, or the user was invited by the sales agent).

So in this scenario, the goal is to get the result table (result) as:

**ResultId**: If there is a record in **User** table, then use the **SalesAgentId**, but if the record is coming from **Invitation** table, then use the **InviteId** for this column.

**Name/Email**: Same logic; if record is in **User** table, use the Name/Email from **User** table, if not, then use the info from **Invitation** table.

**InvitedUser**: If record is in **User** table, then this should be **false**, but if its coming from **Invitation** table, then this should be true.

```
| ResultId | Name      | Email           | InvitedUser |
|----------|-----------|-----------------|-------------|
| 1        | Sales Guy | sales@agent.com | false       |
| 9        | John Doe  | john@doe.com    | true        |
```

I'm not sure what kind of join would help me in this scenario, more or less I need to combine results from 2 queries (I think). Ultimate goal is to get a linq query version of this select, but I think LINQ/EfCore doesn't support Concat when using different data stores.

I'd really appreciate any type of help, or a pointer in the right direction; many thanks in advance.

Comment: You want a filtered list for a specific agent and only the invitees associated with that agent?

Comment: Should probably provide a larger data sample, including case where user is also an invitee. Is John Doe not a user? Output you show looks like result of a UNION query.

Answer (score 0):

The output you show looks like result of a UNION query so consider:

```
SELECT Invitation.InviteID AS ResultID, Invitation.Name, Invitation.Email, True AS InvitedUser
FROM Invitation
UNION
SELECT SalesAgent.SalesAgentID, User.Name, User.Email, False AS InvitedUser
FROM [User] INNER JOIN SalesAgent ON User.UserID = SalesAgent.UserID
WHERE (((User.Name) Not In (SELECT [Name] FROM [Invitation])));
```